# Is there a command to get the no of GPUs per VM Size in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azureportal

I need the number of GPUs per the VM Size in Azure. I can see the list of few GPU Enabled VMS with all needed specs in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/nvv4-series).

[image]

But, I need an automated way of doing this.  I'm aware Web Scraping is an option to do it. But, I want to do it in an Azure way.

Answer (score 0):

Using AZ CLI (quick and dirty, please amend further as needed)

```
az vm list-skus -l westeurope --query "[?family == 'standardNCSv2Family'].[size,name,capabilities[?starts_with(name, 'GPUs')].value]" -o table
```

[image]

You can get the raw JSON with all the properties like this:

```
az vm list-skus -l westeurope --query "[?family == 'standardNCSv2Family'].[size,name,capabilities[?starts_with(name, 'GPUs')].value]" -o table
```